# Memoization for generating permuatation

Tags: algorithm, memoization

Is there any way to have memoization technique of generation the permutation. For example
 for numbers 1234...

For me the problem is that it is taking a lot of memory. Is there any way to in some moderate amount of memory

Comment: Do you mean: how to *enumerate* the permutation?

Answer (score 0):

For any string, say with n distinct characters, n! permutations exist, thus space needed will be large. If you just need to enumerate the permutations, then I would suggest not to store them, but directly display each one as you calculate each one

Comment: if i don't store them and just display then every time i have to recalculate the things that i have already calculated.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it is possible to use memoization for permutation generation (as almost any other computation, when it makes sense). Concrete steps depend on your permutation generation algorithm. For example, if you have function `perms(numbers)` that takes set of numbers (say, `{1, 2, 3, 4}`) and returns set of all permutations (ordered vectors of these numbers, say, `{[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], ...}`) by recursive calling `perms()` with subsets of `numbers`, you can memoize this `perms()` function directly. To do so, create cache as a map, where keys are sets of numbers and values are results of function call.

Concerning second part of your question (about memory). Memoization by its nature uses large amount of memory. You can always fix this amount by using some kind of fixed-size cache (e.g. [LRU/LFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least-Frequently_Used) map), but you should understand that this breaks memoization concept, and some calls to `perms()` will be still computed twice or more times.

Comment: I got your point but i think that the idea of using map is not very good as map tales lgn(logarithmic) time to retrieve an element with the given key.

Comment: @AbdulSamad: Map is abstract data type, it maybe implemented as HashMap, for example, and thus take amortized O(1) (constant time). And even with tree implementation it will be still faster for most of `perms()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the permutations in succession and don't need them all simultaneously, then you may be better off iterating through them lexicographically. Write a function `nextPerm` that takes in a permutation and returns the [next permutation in lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order).